# remove duplicates in polars rust

Tags: dataframe, rust, rust-polars

hi i am trying to remove duplicates based on a column "time" in my dataframe.

i read the official [document](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/polars_core/frame/struct.DataFrame.html#method.unique) which defines the unique() method as follows:

```
pub fn unique(
    &self,
    subset: Option<&[String]>,
    keep: UniqueKeepStrategy,
    slice: Option<(i64, usize)>
) -> PolarsResult<DataFrame>
```

but somehow when i executed :

```
fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let col_name = String::from("time");
    let df = read_csv()?.unique(vec![col_name], UniqueKeep::First)?;
    println!("{:?}", df);
    Ok(())
}
```

i got this error:

```
error[E0433]: failed to resolve: use of undeclared type `UniqueKeep`
   --> src/main.rs:155:49
    |
155 |     let df = read_csv()?.unique(vec![col_name], UniqueKeep::First)?;
    |                                                 ^^^^^^^^^^ use of undeclared type `UniqueKeep`
```

could it be some kind of missing import?
i only loaded the prelude:

```
use polars::prelude::*;
```

Comment: The enum is called `UniqueKeepStrategy`, not `UniqueKeep`.

Comment: ahh, i see. now it returns  `an argument of type Option<(i64, usize)> is missing`, do you know what should i pass to this  `slice: Option<(i64, usize)>`
parameter ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the enum should be `UniqueKeepStrategy`, and the `slice` could be simply `'None'`

also: use  `unique_stable` instead to avoid order being meseed up.

Comment: Where possible, please don't post screenshots of code or error messages so SO stays searchable and accessible. The mention of the function name (`unique_stable`) would have been sufficient. Also weird: This function is on `LazyFrame`, earlier you were working with `DataFrame`.